# How can I tell when a gradle plugin property's evaluation will be deferred?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm using the docker compose plugin from avast. Below is the relevant stanza. How can I tell if mandatoryDockerWebTag() will be called during the configuration phase? Is the only way to inspect the plugin code to figure out when the closures will be called?

Many times I have information that I only want to provide if a task is in the task graph, but that information may be expensive to get, unavailable, or needs to validate a project parameter when its fetched. For instance I don't want someone bringing up the preprod docker image instance of our stack with the "latest" tag, so the mandatoryDockerWebTag() throws an exception if it's "latest", otherwise it returns the current tag.

```
dockerCompose {
    preprod {
        useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose.yml']
        environment.putAll([
                WEB_DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION          : mandatoryDockerWebTag()
        ])
        tcpPortsToIgnoreWhenWaiting = [33333]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell if mandatoryDockerWebTag() will be called during the configuration phase?

I do not believe there is a way to explictly tell how or when a task or configuration is called in Gradle without either:

1. Examine the source of the plugin you are using.
2. Examine the [build scan](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/) report.

> For instance I don't want someone bringing up the preprod docker image instance of our stack

Unfortunately, you do not have control over what a plugin author does to your Gradle configuration. They have free/complete access to your project and can configure/alter at will as far as I know.

Good/effective plugin authors (IMO) utilize [configuration avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html). It applies to not only tasks, but configurations as well.